# magento 2 Issue with Rest Api zero price first time any solution

Tags: magento2, api

Products added to cart with REST API give total prices equal to zero I added my comments in github also but no response from magento team did any one resolved this issue

```
https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/2991
```